# Can I use an example in a field name?

Tags: terminology, input-fields

Is it acceptible to include an example/illustration in a parameter label?

We have a feature that can read numbers imported via Excel spreadsheet as minor currency units, meaning if the user enters 60 the system understands .60.

We have a paramater that activates this feature, when ticked.

The proper general terms I have found for cents, pence, and the like are not very clear and therefore we can't find a good, short way to express the feature in the short space alloted for the parameter label.

My question is, can I give the following title:

> Amounts are in Minor Units (e.g. cents, pence)

## **Process flow:**

1. The user enters amounts (such as the number 60) in the spreadsheet. These numbers are all cents.
2. The user goes to the import paramaters screen
3. The user specifies the currency of these amounts (USD in our case)
4. The user marks this parameter to tell the system that all amounts should be read as ________ (minor units/fractional units/other, better word...).

Comment: Could we see a wireframe or something that shows the amount of space you're talking about? - it would also be great to know if you've tried other thinks like a denomination selector alongside the field (£,$,p,c for example).

Comment: What about changing the system?

Comment: @AndrewMartin - i have edited the question a bit, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @DimitraMiha, I am not in the position to change the system, furthermore I don't understand exactly what you mean and how that can help

Comment: If I understood correctly, the only thing that changes is the unit (you don't change the number the user enters). I think making a distinction between Major units and Minor units is not helping. It might be better to simply say Unit X, Unit Y. no?

Comment: @Alvaro, this isn't possible because the currency is also determined by the user at the same stage as this parameter.

Comment: When you say *if the user enters 60* - where does the user enter this amount? In spreadsheet? Does the spreadsheet is meant to enter only minor amounts? How does the user know they have to enter minor amounts only? Do you want to use the title for that field?

Comment: @Dipak, i have edited the question once again to try and clarify. The user doesn't need to know, he decides according to the practice he wants to follow. if he needs to fill out a spreadsheet with cent values, it will be much easier to just put in the numbers without adding a decimal every time.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you want to put the example in the field label? One common pattern I've seen is putting the example in the field itself by default, which disappears when the user actually focuses on the field for data entry.

[image: Example]

Comment: it's a checkbox....

Comment: It doesn't sound like a checkbox from your original description. It sounds like a currency field. You should probably provide some screenshots, wireframes, etc. because clearly your design problem is causing quite a bit of confusion among the people trying to offer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions from me:

> The user marks this parameter to tell the system that all amounts
>   should be read as --------------

- Nickels & Pennies
- Units less than 1 dollar / Units less than a dollar